# show snackbar on fcm notification on every screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, snackbar

I want to show snackbar when in app notification arrive.
But  when I configure firebase on first screen, snackbar shows only when user is on that screen.
I try to create a class to get BuildContext and show snackbar based on it but doesn't work and not show snackbar.

This is my HomeScreen.dart:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      NotificationManger.init(context: context);
      Fcm.initConfigure();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, Store<AppState>>(
      converter: (store) => store,
      onInit: (store) => initApp(store),
      builder: (context, store) {
        return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
          create: (context) {
            return HomeBloc(homeRepository: homeRepository)..add(ScreenOpened());
          },
          child: BlocListener<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
            listener: (context, state) async {},
            child: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Scaffold(
                  key: _scaffoldKey,
                  ...
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Fcm.dart

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }
  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }
}

class Fcm {
  static final FirebaseRepository repository = FirebaseRepository();
  static final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  static initConfigure() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) _iosPermission();

    _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions();
    _fcm.autoInitEnabled();

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async => NotificationManger.onMessage(message),
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async => NotificationManger.onLaunch(message),
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async => NotificationManger.onResume(message),
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    );

    _fcm.getToken().then((String token) {
      print('token: $token');
      repository.setUserNotifToken(token);
    });
  }

  static _iosPermission() {
    _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my NotificationManager.dart:

```
class NotificationManger {
  static BuildContext _context;

  static init({@required BuildContext context}) {
    _context = context;
  }

  static onMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(message);
    _showSnackbar(data: message);
  }

  static onLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(message);
  }

  static onResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(message);
  }

  static _showSnackbar({@required Map<String, dynamic> data}) {
    // showDialog(context: _context, builder: (_) => );
    SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        data['data']['title'],
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Vazir',
          fontSize: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: ColorPalette.primary,
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45.0),
      ),
      elevation: 3.0,
    );
    Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

`main.dart`

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Store<AppState> store;
  App(this.store);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using redux and bloc, so any approach with these tools is ok for me.

This is my sample screen:

```
class Reminders extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('reminders'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION**:
Add `NotificationManger.init(globalKey: _scaffoldKey);` to all screens solve the problem.

```
class Reminders extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NotificationManger.init(globalKey: _scaffoldKey);

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('reminders'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Using*Get* library to using only one function and no need to add it in all screen: https://pub.dev/packages/get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with registering scaffolds for your NotificationManager widget since every time a new scaffold is added to the stack for a new screen, you need to register that screen's scaffold in the NotificationManager. This is because the line:

`Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(snackBar);`

in your NoticicationManager will only look up the widget tree until the first scaffold it finds and call it there. Since you call `NotificationManger.init(context: context);` in your HomeScreen widget and pass the context of the HomeScreen, it will only live inside that scaffold. So, if you navigate away from the HomeScreen to a new widget with a different scaffold it will not have the NotificationManager as a child.

To fix the issue be sure you call `Fcm.initConfigure();` in the first page that loads for the app, and for any pages you navigate to call `NotificationManger.init(context: context);` in either the initState() method for stateful widgets to register the current scaffold of that page or if they are stateless widgets, you can add it in the build method before returning the scaffold.

Comment: I have new scaffold for my screens, so How can I do something like this?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a recommendation on what to do, see if it works and if you have further questions try adding your main.dart or some clarity on how you are navigating away from HomeScreen

Comment: Did you try moving `Fcm.initConfigure();` to your main.dart, since it is a stateless widget in the build method and adding `NotificationManger.init(context: context);` to each of your pages initState methods?

Comment: I want to configure fcm when user logged in. So my homeScreen is root screen when user logged in. and build method of my homeScreen runs when navigating.

Comment: Okay then that page can stay the same, can you show me an example of how you navigate to a different page and the code for that page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210887/discussion-between-jwildsmith-and-behappy).